# App Insights: Disable SQL Dependency telemetry

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Application Insights for a website (Azure App Service).
On that I'm using a clustered Umbraco setup and hangfire. These two alone keep hitting the database every minute and are flooding my 'App Insights'.

So my question is, how do I disable the Sql Dependency Tracker?
I've had a look at the ApplicationInsights.config and couldn't find anything obvious.
I can see `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector` which is probably responsible, but I don't want to remove all types of dependency telemetry, **only** sql.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your best bet here is to use a Telemetry Processor to filter out certain types of dependency requests. Check out these resources below for information.

[Sampling, filtering and preprocessing telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling/#filtering)

[Request filtering in Application Insights with Telemetry Processor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/)

An example processor might look like this.

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;

public class NoSQLDependencies : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // Link processors to each other in a chain.
    public NoSQLDependencies(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (IsSQLDependency(item)) { return; }
        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    private bool IsSQLDependency(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
        if (dependency?.DependencyTypeName == "SQL")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know what the possible values for DependencyTypeName are?  I'd like to stop tracking access to blob storage

Comment: @Mick have you ever found solution for this?

Comment: @batmaci yes i did.  I created a ITelemetryProcessor ran the application in the debugger, put a conditional break point in the processor until I found the telemetry I wanted to block.  Inspect the properties of the ITelemetry item allowed me to define the criteria to filter out the particular telemetry I wanted to filter out, as illustrated in this answer

Comment: I've just used this and I needed to change from a `DependencyTypeName` to checking for `DependencyKind`. Apart from that, works well.

Comment: Found the source at https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/386470e973698327e0873ba8b58f35878f6f0bc1/Src/DependencyCollector/Shared/Implementation/RemoteDependencyConstants.cs

            public const string SQL = "SQL";
            public const string HTTP = "Http";

            public const string AzureBlob = "Azure blob";
            public const string AzureTable = "Azure table";
            public const string AzureQueue = "Azure queue";

Comment: can one disable for only hangfire sql. I still want to see standard sql queries?

Comment: Both `DependencyTypeName` and `DependencyKind` are obsolete now. Use just `Type`

Answer (score 1):

We filter out just hangfire SQL using a telemetry processor like this, in a .net5 asp.net project. Note that we use a different database for Hangfire so the telemetry processor can easily out hangfire SQL by checking if it's connecting to the Hangfire database.

Within `Startup.Configure()`:

```
var hangFireConnectionString = // ... get from somewhere

configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use(next => new IgnoreHangfireTelemetry(next,hangFireConnectionString))
    .Build();
```

Here's the processor class:

```
public class IgnoreHangfireTelemetry : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor next;
    private readonly string hangfireDashboardPath;
    private readonly string sqlDatabase;  // name of the hangfire db

    public IgnoreHangfireTelemetry(
        ITelemetryProcessor next,
        string sqlConnectionString = null,
        string hangfireDashboardPath = "/hangfire")
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sqlConnectionString);

            sqlDatabase = builder.InitialCatalog;
        }

        this.hangfireDashboardPath = hangfireDashboardPath ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hangfireDashboardPath));
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

        // If it's a request for Hangfire Dashboard don't record it
        if (request != null
            && request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(hangfireDashboardPath))
        {
            return;
        }

        var telemetry = item as DependencyTelemetry;

        // If it's a SQL dependency to the Hangfire db don't record it
        if (telemetry != null)
        {
            if (sqlDatabase != null  && telemetry.Type == "SQL"
                && telemetry.Target.EndsWith($"| {sqlDatabase}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return;
            }
        
            if (telemetry.Type == "SQL"
                && telemetry.Name.ToLower().Contains("hangfire")
                && telemetry.Success.GetValueOrDefault(false))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Looks like it's not Hangfire, process the telemetry as usual.
        next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

If you don't use a separate Hangfire db, you could achieve the same thing by inspecting other [DependencyTelemetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.dependencytelemetry?view=azure-dotnet#properties) properties, e.g. look at DependencyTelemetry.Data or .CommandName (which holds the SQL statement) and check if it contains `[Hangfire]` (or another db schema name if you've changed Hangfire to use a different schema). If you're just filtering on sql you'll need to filter out a few more commands. Just step through using the debugger and see which ones you need to exclude. For example, in above code my `sqlBackend` object looks like this (note that "." is my SQL Server name, i.e. running locally, and "Hangfire" is the DB name where my Hangfire tables are):

[image: debug-info]

Sometimes the sqlBackend.Name property has values like `. | Hangfire | Open`, or `. | Hangfire | sp_getapplock`, but the `Target` property is still just ``. | Hangfire` e.g.:

[image]

Comment: how do we do this in .NET 6?

Comment: I don't think it's changed in .net 6

Comment: When I troubleshoot the `telemetry.Name`, I can't see `hangfire` and thus it will process the telemetry as usual. The `telemetry.Name` I always get is `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices`

Comment: @Steve I suspect it’s the line matching `telemetry.Target` to our Hangfire db that does it for us, not the `telemetry.Name`.

Comment: `telemetry.Target` value is also `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices` where xx is IP address of my db. And `telemetry.Name` value is `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices | Open`. I wonder how this `telemetry.Target` is formed? Can it be customized?

Comment: @Steve - is "myservices" the name of the database where Hangfire tables are? In that case it's the same as what I see, it's just that I use a separate database named "Hangfire". As I mentioned in my answer above, you could inspect other properties like `CommandName` to decide whether to filter out the command.

Comment: Yes, myservices is my database name. Yeah both my services and my hangfire is sharing the same database. The `CommandName` is `Open`. Sometimes  `CommandName` is empty.

Comment: When the `CommandName` is `Open`, then the `telementry.Target` is `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices | Open`. When `CommandName` is empty, then `telementry.Target` is `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices`

Comment: ok, then I guess there's nothing in there that says "I'm doing Hangfire stuff" for all of the events. If you check for "[Hangfire]" and "sp_getapplock" etc in the command you'll probably be able to filter out most of them and perhaps that's good enough for you? Best to ask on hangfire.io forum and/or find out where that info comes from. Perhaps there's a way you can get Hangfire to do it differently, either putting something into the telemetry name or object, or something else.