# How to make application insights only store exceptions and custom events

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights

I have setup our applications to use application insights. Unfortunately we continue to go over our limits every month. I initially went through and gutted out excessive telemetry information it was sending. After some research I have found that you can also tell App Insights what telemetry information to hold onto. Has anyone found how you can tell App Insights to only save Exceptions, and Custom Events?

I have no need for the excessive amount of requests, page views, dependencies, and traces that App Insights wants to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this answer I posted a little bit ago--this answere assumes a .NET application. You can use the same concept of a TelemetryProcessor to filter out all telemetry of a certain type.

[App Insights: Disable SQL Dependency telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320886/app-insights-disable-sql-dependency-telemetry/38321304#38321304)

Also, as a nuclear approach you can remove all of the Initializers, Modules and Processors from the ApplicationInsights.config (or just remove it and set the iKey in code) and remove the ApplicationInsightsTracking module from the web.config.

It would then be up to you to call TrackEvent() and TrackException() explicitly to capture your telemetry.

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure application insights in your project? If you have done by right clicking on project > Add > Application insights, VS installs bunch of nuget packages which you might not need.

**Follow below steps for manual installation :**

You can install 'ApplicationInsights.Web' nuget package (with ignore dependencies option) which will ApplicationInsights.config file for you. Copy the Instrumentation Key and add it to your ApplicationInsights.config file. Follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs#manual-installation) and install the package of your choice with lowest/Ignore dependencies option.

Or simply uninstall the 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector' package and you won't see any dependency related insights.