# MS Application Insights - How to throttle Sql Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to tell Application Insights to capture only a percentage of the data related to **SQL dependencies**? something like, 10%? If not, is there a way to disable it all together?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320886/app-insights-disable-sql-dependency-telemetry/38321304#38321304

Comment: Please try to follow James Davis - MSFT's answer and find out whether it could help you.

Comment: @JamesDavis-MSFT you're solution worked perfectly fine, pls post-it as answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comments below this answer should help when trying to implement a custom TelemetryProcessor.

[App Insights: Disable SQL Dependency telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320886/app-insights-disable-sql-dependency-telemetry/38321304#38321304)

Answer (score 1):

You can "throttle" (or sample, as Microsoft calls it) in different ways. One way is to throttle everything, using the built-in configuration options, but if you want to throttle only specific dependencies, you need to implement your own ITelemetryChannel.
A guide as to how this is done can be found here: http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/05/06/diy-data-sampling/

Then, in the Send(ITelemetry item) method, you can check if the incoming item is a dependency and related to SQL, it will look something like this:

```
if (item is DependencyTelemetry)
{  
    var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;  
    if (dependency.DependencyTypeName == "SQL")  
    {  
        //implement throttling from the guide  
    }  
}
```

As the link shows, you will need to create an instance of ServerTelemetryChannel and invoke the Send() method on this - you need to do this for any telemetry items that you want to actually send to application insights.
This means you can also use this implementation to completely filter out any SQL dependency telemetry like this:

```
public void Send(ITelemetry item)
{
    if (item is DependencyTelemetry)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;  
        if (dependency.DependencyTypeName == "SQL")  
        {  
            return;
        }  
    }        
    this.channel.Send(item);
}
```

Comment: I read it and implemented it, replacing the standart node in the applicationinsights.config file, but even leaving the implementation for `Send(..)` empty, I still see all kinds of telemetry all the same... breakpoints are also not working...

Comment: Your telemetry channel is implementing both ITelemetryChannel and ITelemetryModule? 
And, can you show the line <TelemetryChannel> line from your applicationinsights.config file?

Comment: @Imms90 i'm initializing my custom channel via code now. My breakpoint are being hit, but I still get logs even with an blank `send` method... is that because i'm using a dev env perhaps?

Comment: what kind of logs? I just implemented it myself and if I have an empty Send method, I don't get anything in application insights