# Unable to find hangfire in telemetry.Name

Tags: c#, hangfire

I need to exclude log from hangfire in Azure App Insight. Referring to this post, [App Insights: Disable SQL Dependency telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320886/app-insights-disable-sql-dependency-telemetry)

```
if (telemetry.Type == "SQL"
    && telemetry.Name.ToLower().Contains("hangfire")
    && telemetry.Success.GetValueOrDefault(false))
{
    return;
}
```

When I troubleshoot the `telemetry.Name`, I can't see `hangfire` and thus it will process the telemetry as usual. The `telemetry.Name` I get is `xx.xxx.xx.xx,xxx | myservices`

```
next.Process(item);
```

Sample log (modified version because got ip address)

```
10/25/2022, 10:57:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:52:10 PM

10/25/2022, 10:47:10 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop Hangfire from logging by Adding an `"Hangfire": "None"` entry in `Logging` section of your `appsettings.json` file.

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Hangfire": "None"
  }
}
```

Comment: After changing Hangfire to None, it still logs at Azure App Insight.

Comment: @Steve Can you include in your question a sample of those messages you see?

Comment: Ok I have added some sample log