# Application Insights: How to disable SQL Dependency telemetry

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We use Azure Application Insights for a website (Azure App Service) and the SQL Dependency logs are filling up the logs.
[image: Transaction logs]

We have have commented the following line in our ApplicationInsights.config
`<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>`

Where can we disable these?

Comment: If you disabled the dependency tracking module by commenting out the DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule is should work. Make sure all instances are runnign with the new config file.

Comment: @Nele . kindly check this thread it may helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320886/app-insights-disable-sql-dependency-telemetry?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have found the similar issue in SO that is regarding the disabling SQL Dependency telemetry (Application Insights) where James Davis provided the resolution]([App Insights: Disable SQL Dependency telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38320886/16630138)) "https://stackoverflow.com/q/38320886/16630138)") to it which might help to your requirement

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;

public class SuccessfulDependencyFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public SuccessfulDependencyFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        if (!OKtoSend(item)) { return; }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    // Example: replace with your own criteria.
    private bool OKtoSend (ITelemetry item)
    {
        var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
        if (dependency == null) return true;

        return dependency.Success != true;
    }
}
```

Reference [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/)